# How to add two list as key value pair?

Tags: dart

i have two list as follows:
record=[1,2,3,4]
colRecord=[a,b,c,d]
I want this two list in following output:
data= ["1":a, "2":b, "3":c, "4":d]
using dart

Answer (score 2):

You can get a Map with [Map.fromIterables](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterables.html)

```
var record = [1,2,3,4];
var colRecord = [a,b,c,d];
var result = Map.fromIterables(record, colRecord);
```